# Whats wrong with XCODE 9.1 Storyboard ? It becomes slowest thing on earth to Open

Tags: storyboard, xcode9

Xcode 9.1's storyboard become slowest thing in this application. does any one experience same thing and get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9.1 Interface Builder still has a lot of performance issues. Apple knows that, but filing a bug report should help to put more emphasis on fixing.

It helps if you open your storyboard in a separate window. That way it stays in memory and does not have to be reloaded every time you switch a tab in your main project window. You can minimize the storyboard window while you don't need it.